# How can i iterate through a TwoDHashMap in java??

Tags: java

I'm using the code

```
TwoDHashMap<Integer, DateTime, KeyNamePair> shiftDetails = new TwoDHashMap<Integer, DateTime, KeyNamePair>();
```

Please help to iterate over each pair of key!

Comment: what is `TwoDHashMap`, from where this type is?

Comment: @alex2410 It's from the spiffy framework. http://spiffyframework.sourceforge.net/javadoc/spiffy/core/util/TwoDHashMap.html

Comment: @blackpanther, same class exists in Super CSV library http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/util/TwoDHashMap.html

Comment: Let me know how to iterate? i m new to java!!

Comment: Author, please, edit tags to clearify your question

Comment: link might help http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.supercsv/super-csv/2.0.0-beta-1/org/supercsv/util/TwoDHashMap.java#TwoDHashMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method `keySet()` to get a set of the keys of the outermost map. Then iterate over the that.